# ¿Un método sin implementar de una clase abstracto debe ser abstracto?

Tags: java, clase-abstracta

Estoy construyendo una clase abstracta y quiero dejar dos métodos sin implementar, veo que java me da un error y se soluciona si las pongo como abstractas, ¿es correcto? ¿no puedo dejar un método sin implementar sin declararlo abstracto?

```
/**
 * DEFINICIÓN DE LA CLASE ABSTRACTA POLIREGULAR
 * ==============================================================================
 * 
 * @author LUIS QUESADA ROMERO
 */

// PAQUETE AL QUE PERTENECE
package modelos;

public abstract class PoliRegular { // INICIO DE LA CLASE PRINCIPAL POLIREGULAR

    // ATRIBUTOS DE CLASE //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    protected int nLados;
    protected double lLado;
    protected boolean relleno;
    private final String[] colores = {"NEGRO", "VERDE", "ROJO", "AZUL"};
    protected String color = colores[0]; // PONEMOS EL COLOR NEGRO POR DEFECTO

    private double valor;


    // MÉTODOS CONSTRUCTORES ///////////////////////////////////////////////////

    /**
     *  CONSTRUCTOR CON DOS PARAMETROS
     * ====================================
     * 
     * @param lLado -> LONGUITUD DEL LADO
     * @param colorIndice -> COLOR
     */
    PoliRegular(double lLado, int colorIndice) {
        this.lLado = lLado;
        this.color = colores[colorIndice];
    }

    /**
     *  CONSTUCTOR CON UN PAREMETRO
     * ====================================
     * @param lLado -> LONGUITUD DEL LADO
     */
    PoliRegular(double lLado) {
        this.lLado = lLado;
        this.color = colores[0];
    }

    /**
     * CONSTRUCTOR SIN PARAMETROS
     * ===========================
     */
    public PoliRegular() {
    }

    // MÉTODOS GETTER /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    public int getnLados() {
        return nLados;
    }

    public double getlLado() {
        return lLado;
    }

    public boolean isRelleno() {
        return relleno;
    }

    public String[] getColores() {
        return colores;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    // METODOS SETTER //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    public void setnLados(int nLados) {
        this.nLados = nLados;
    }

    public void setlLado(double lLado) {
        this.lLado = lLado;
    }

    public void setRelleno(boolean relleno) {
        this.relleno = relleno;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    // MÉTODO TO STRING ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "PoliRegular{" + "nLados=" + nLados + ", lLado=" + lLado + ", relleno=" + relleno + ", colores=" + colores + ", color=" + color + '}';
    }

    // MÉTODOS DE CLASE ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    // MÉTODO PARA CALCULAR EL ÁREA
    public abstract double obtenerArea();

    // MÉTODO PARA CALCUAR EL PERIMETRO
    public double obtenerPerimetro(){
        return lLado*nLados;
    }

    // MÉTODO PARA AGRANDAR
    public double agrandar(double valor){
        lLado += valor;
        return lLado;
    }

    // MÉTODO PARA REDUCIR
    public double reducir(double valor){
        lLado -= valor;
        return lLado;
    }

    // MÉTODO PARA ROTAR
    public void rotar();


    // MÉTODO PARA DIBUJAR
    public void dibujar();

} // FIN DE LA CLASE PRINCIPAL
```

Como decía sino defino como abstractos los métodos rotar() y dibujar() el IDE me carga "missing methos body, or declare abstract".
Es para un ejercicio de DAW, pero no encuentro información al respecto, lo que quiero saber es el porque, sino de nada me sirve estudiarlo, no entiendo el porque.

Comment: Seria bueno que agregues codigo para ver que estas haciendo mal, tambien que error es mostrado, agrega a tu pregunta mas detalles.

Answer (score 2):

Conozco tres formas de dejar un método sin implementar:
1) definirlo dentro de una interfaz.
2) defnirlo como un método abstracto dentro de una clase abstracta.
3) definirlo como no abstracto pero sin implementación, para que subclases lo implementen, por ejemplo

```
public void doOperation() {}  <<Este método no es abstracto pero no hace nada. Subclases lo reimplementan para que haga algo.
```

Otra cuarta opción es tener el método no abstracto y que tire una excepción y que subclases lo implelmenten. Por ejemplo:

```
public void doOperation() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("no implementada");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Te faltan unas llaves por eso te da erro en los ultimo métodos. mira mis últimos metodos y mira los tuyos.

```
public abstract class PoliRegular {
protected int nLados;
protected double lLado;
protected boolean relleno;
private final String[] colores = {"NEGRO", "VERDE", "ROJO", "AZUL"};
protected String color = colores[0]; // PONEMOS EL COLOR NEGRO POR DEFECTO

private double valor;


// MÉTODOS CONSTRUCTORES ///////////////////////////////////////////////////

/**
 *  CONSTRUCTOR CON DOS PARAMETROS
 * ====================================
 * 
 * @param lLado -> LONGUITUD DEL LADO
 * @param colorIndice -> COLOR
 */
PoliRegular(double lLado, int colorIndice) {
    this.lLado = lLado;
    this.color = colores[colorIndice];
}

/**
 *  CONSTUCTOR CON UN PAREMETRO
 * ====================================
 * @param lLado -> LONGUITUD DEL LADO
 */
PoliRegular(double lLado) {
    this.lLado = lLado;
    this.color = colores[0];
}

/**
 * CONSTRUCTOR SIN PARAMETROS
 * ===========================
 */
public PoliRegular() {
}

// MÉTODOS GETTER /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
public int getnLados() {
    return nLados;
}

public double getlLado() {
    return lLado;
}

public boolean isRelleno() {
    return relleno;
}

public String[] getColores() {
    return colores;
}

public String getColor() {
    return color;
}

// METODOS SETTER //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

public void setnLados(int nLados) {
    this.nLados = nLados;
}

public void setlLado(double lLado) {
    this.lLado = lLado;
}

public void setRelleno(boolean relleno) {
    this.relleno = relleno;
}

public void setColor(String color) {
    this.color = color;
}

// MÉTODO TO STRING ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "PoliRegular{" + "nLados=" + nLados + ", lLado=" + lLado + ", relleno=" + relleno + ", colores=" + colores + ", color=" + color + '}';
}
// MÉTODO PARA CALCULAR EL ÁREA
public abstract double obtenerArea();

// MÉTODO PARA CALCUAR EL PERIMETRO
public double obtenerPerimetro(){
    return lLado*nLados;
}

// MÉTODO PARA AGRANDAR
public double agrandar(double valor){
    lLado += valor;
    return lLado;
}

// MÉTODO PARA REDUCIR
public double reducir(double valor){
    lLado -= valor;
    return lLado;
}

// MÉTODO PARA ROTAR
public void rotar(){

};


// MÉTODO PARA DIBUJAR
public void dibujar(){

};
```

}